# IIS ignoring the mvc routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-10

It's been weeks since I published my MVC application to my local IIS as testing environment. So happens that after the publish it gives the 403.14 Forbidden Error

[image]

I tried enabling the directory browsing but then it just shows a list of the files from the server.

This is the current features that I have turned on:
[image]

This is the reference/resources used by the project:

[image]

Is there anything that I have completely forgot to install? This project was handed to me earlier this year and I dont have any idea on how to publish an mvc application.

Hoping that you could give me light to this question.

Thank you all!

Comment: How did you deploy the MVC project to IIS? Is it by publishing the project to a folder?

Comment: Essentially yes. I used the publish website option from VS2015 and i pointed it out on a folder on the inetpub folder

Comment: Will this problem occur if you publish an MVC template project? I have to determine whether this is a project issue or an IIS issue.

Comment: @DingPeng i think this an IIS issue. I followed all the necessary instructions of the programmer before me but not of it works.